# Creating image from datauri not working only when data sent from POST

Tags: php, base64, data-uri

Using PHP, I'm trying to generate an image from a datauri. It works fine if I hardcode the string to decode like this:

```
$sourceString = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ8AAAArCAYAAABmQFqDA..."; // I truncated the actual string for this example...
$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test.jpeg';
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($sourceString));
imagejpeg($image, $destination, 100);
```

This works fine and generates an image called "test.jpeg" in my root folder.

My problem is that if I take the datauri from a POST variable, it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
$sourceString = $_POST['data'];
$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test.jpeg';
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($sourceString));
imagejpeg($image, $destination, 100);
```

In the above example, I confirmed that $sourceString contains the same exact contents as when I hardcode it in my first example. In the second example, I get the following errors:

```
[09-Sep-2015 16:54:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromstring(): gd-png:  fatal libpng error: Read Error: truncated data in request.image_paste.php on line 10
[09-Sep-2015 16:54:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromstring(): gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition in request.image_paste.php on line 10
[09-Sep-2015 16:54:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromstring(): Passed data is not in 'PNG' format in request.image_paste.php on line 10
[09-Sep-2015 16:54:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromstring(): Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in request.image_paste.php on line 10
[09-Sep-2015 16:54:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in request.image_paste.php on line 11
```

I don't understand what could be wrong. I tried casting the variable as a string:

```
$sourceString = (string)$_POST['data'];
```

But that didn't help.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: What does `$_POST['data']` contain? Is it a base64-encoded string when it arrives?

Comment: maybe the POST'ed data is somehow being urlencoded ? just guessing...You may also want to share the exact $sourceString here, if possible.